# PhoneGap: Inject JS into HTML on page load through Java on Android

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

I like to inject js code into html when the application is done loading through Java. Actually, I have some code which I don't want anyone to see when they extract the application apk, and when that particular js in is embedded in Java code it would be a little difficult to extract. I know the complete java code for the apk can be decompiled, but this be make things little difficult. 
Can anyone help in this?

I am using PhoneGap/Cordova 2.1.0 for Android.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

some solutions:

1. write plugin, call you code within a cordova.ready callback
2. extend the droidgap and call `super.loadUrl("javascript:window.alert()");`

I would suggest the first one.